# Angular how to avoid a checkbox from being checked?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-template

When a checkbox is clicked I show a modal with two buttons, accept and do not accept. The checkbox should only be checked if accept button is checked.

For testing purposes I tried to create this checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="foo()" [checked]="false">
```

Expecting it to execute foo method of my component but never get checked. The problem is that it gets checked! I coming from React background and this is very frustrating.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I also tried

```
<input type="checkbox" name="show_recurrency" (change)="foo()" [(ngModel)]="checkout.recurrency" id="show_recurrency" />
```

```
        foo(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.error('foooooooooooooooo', e);
          this.checkout.recurrency = false;
          return;
        }
```

Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can handle the `click` event:

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="foo($event)" [checked]="false">
```

and call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the change:

```
foo(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("foo was called");
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubd49e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it an `[(ngModel)]`, and inside `foo()` force it back to false.